# Does python's re.sub take an array as the input parameter?

Tags: python, regex, arrays, replace, preg-replace-callback

According to http://www.php2python.com/wiki/function.preg-replace-callback/ re.sub is the python equivlant of PHP's preg_replace_callback, but the php version takes an array for the strings to be matched, so you can pass multiple strings, but the re.sub appears to take only a single string.

Is that right or is it my weak knowledge of python?

Comment: Check the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub); does it say you can pass a list?

Comment: I have checked that, but being a python newbie I want to confirm, in case there may be another python library procedure that does the same, in that case the website mentioned is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only takes a single string http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do it on an array, you can use a list comprehension, e.g.

```
>>> array_of_strings = ["3a1", "1b2", "1c", "d"]
>>> [re.sub("[a-zA-Z]", "", elem) for elem in array_of_strings]
["31", "12", "1", ""]
```

though if you're using a complicated expression, you should probably use [`re.compile`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.compile) on the pattern first

Comment: In preg_replace_callback the first parameter is an array of different search->replace patterns and elem is a string that contains one or more of the search->replace patterns.

Comment: @vfclists, you could do that with a series of nested re.sub's (since they each return a string).

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party I know, but if this was a requirement for a many step process you wanted to encapsulate into a function, then you could process through numpy vectorize:

```
def EliminateAlpha(elem):
    return re.sub("[a-zA-Z]", "", elem)

ElimAlphaArray = np.vectorize(ElimateAlpha)

array_of_strings = ["3a1", "1b2", "1c", "d"]
print(ElimAlphaArray(array_of_strings))

['31' '12' '1' '']
```

Of course, you can use the re.sub function directly into vectorize:

```
ElimAlphaArr = np.vectorize(re.sub)
print(ElimAlphaArr("[a-zA-Z]", "", array_of_strings))

['31' '12' '1' '']
```